# ¿Por que mi programa imprime basura?

Tags: ensamblador, nasm

tengo el siguiente código:

```
[bits 16]

segment .text
    global start

start:
    lea si,[msg]
    call caracter

    mov ah,4Ch ; end the program
    int 21

caracter:
    mov al,[si]
    cmp al,0
    jz endprint

    inc si
    mov ah,0Eh
    int 10h
    jmp caracter

endprint:
    ret

segment .data
    msg db 'Hola mundo',0
```

Se supone que imprime el mensaje msg carácter por carácter hasta encontrarse con un 0, el problema es que solo me imprime basura ¿que hago mal?

Comment: Hace tiempo que no toco ensamblador, así que no me atrevo a dar una respuesta firme pero...¿Es posible que "lea si,[msg]" deba ser "lea si,msg" pues "msg" ya es el puntero en si?

Comment: @ArnauCastellví La verdad es que al comienzo lo hice así pero me daba error con los operandos en esa instrucción

Comment: Entonces es probable que debas usar un acumulador intermedio, por ejemplo "mov hl,msg lea si,ah" o algo parecido, mira que datos acepta "lea si" y adaptalo. Disculpa no poder ser mas preciso, debe hacer 20 años que no lo toco XD
EDIT: Por lo que leo, "lea SI,msg" debería ser correcto...

Comment: También pienso que es lo correcto pero el nasm simplemente me lanza error: invalid: combination of opcode and operands

Comment: ¿Probaste a usar DI en vez de SI?

Comment: @ArnauCastellví ya consegui solucionar mi problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de investigar mas a fondo, el problema era realmente muy sencillo de solucionar, solo necesitaba agregar 1 linea al comienzo del documento `org  0x100` quedaría así:

```
[bits 16]
org  0x100 ; aqui la linea que faltaba para que funcionara

segment .text
    global start

start:
    lea si,[msg]
    call caracter

    mov ah,4Ch ; end the program
    int 21     ; hello darkness my old friend

caracter:
    mov al,[si]
    cmp al,0
    jz endprint

    mov ah,0Eh ; imprime el caracter
    int 10h
    inc si     ; avanza al siguiente caracter
    jmp caracter



endprint:
    ret

segment .data
    msg db "Hola mundo",0
```

Esto es necesario debido a que según la documentación oficial de Nasm:

> In this model, the code you end up writing starts at 0x100...

Lo que quiere decir que comenzamos a trabajar en la dirección de memoria 0x100 y por lo tanto es necesario ajustar el `location counter` a esa posición lo cual se hace con `org  0x100`, sin esta linea era evidente que se imprimía basura puesto que la información no estaba en la dirección que uno pensaba.

Comment: Ese es el encabezado para crear un ejecutable  .com (creo recordar) creí que ya lo haría el propio compilador jeje,.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví exacto :)